# Lithium framework: how to obtain controller name in layout

Tags: php, layout, controller, lithium

I'm in a lithium layout file and I'd like to echo the name of the current controller (to use as a CSS class later). How can I obtain the current controller name?

Thanks,
aeno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean you are in a View?

If so, it's pretty simple to get the controller or other parts of the route/request ...

```
<?=$this->_request->controller;?>
```

That will get you the **Controller** but you can get just about anything from your route you'd need. So assuming you have a route like ...

```
Router::connect('/{:controller}/{:action}/{:id}');
```

You can use both of the following in your view:

```
<?=$this->_request->action;?>

<?=$this->_request->id;?>
```

Or you could have a fancier route like ..

```
Router::connect('/{:id}/{:area}/{:controller}/{:action}/');
```

This would be for a url like:

> http://mysite.com/123/media/photos/edit/

Now you can do something like ...

```
<?=$this->_request->area;?>
```

To get the "area" portion of the url, etc. You get the idea.

Comment: you really should use `$this->request()` instead: http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template/view/Renderer::request%28%29

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used in any Lithium layout or view to look up the current Controller, convert it to a suitable CSS class name, and set it as the class attribute of a div:

```
<?php
    $controller = $this->request()->controller;
    $controller_css_class = strtolower(\lithium\util\Inflector::slug($controller));
?>

<div class="<?=$controller_css_class; ?>"></div>
```

The request class is documented here: http://li3.me/docs/lithium/action/Request